# 'push' element to the subarray within nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have listed several ways to create nested array and add value to sub array:

*Way 1: works!*

```
// Create empty nested array:    
var arrs = [[],[],[]];
arrs[0].push(1);
arrs[1].push(2);
arrs[2].push(3);
```

Then, not surprisingly, `arrs` is updated:

```
[[1],[2],[3]]
```

*Way 2: works!*

```
var arrs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   arrs[i] = [];
 }

arrs[0].push(1);
arrs[1].push(2);
arrs[2].push(3);
```

`arrs`:

```
 [[1],[2],[3]]
```

Way 3: ?

```
var arrs = [];
var subArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   arrs[i] = subArr;
 }

arrs[0].push(1);
arrs[1].push(2);
arrs[2].push(3);
```

`arrs`:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

My question: why the *way 3* leads to `arrs` result as `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]` rather than `[[1],[2],[3]]`?

Comment: it takes the same object reference.

Comment: Interesting observation, you are making changes to `subArr ` thrice and the same changed object is referred by 3 objects in `arr`

Comment: `Array.from({length: 3}, (_, i) => ([i + 1]));` ... just saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your third way, you are assigning each element of `arrs` to the same array by reference: `subArr`. There is no copying, all three items in `arrs` point to the same value in memory.

Naturally, when you push to `arrs[0]`, you are then pushing to `subArr`. Repeat 3 times, and you then have the result you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's the same object!

If you did

```
arrs[i] = [];
```

You'd get a different result! You'd assign a new array each time instead of a reference to one array.

This is an easy trap to fall into in any programming language.

Comment: Exactly. I start my first programming language as Python (in which assignment pass the variable values instead of reference). I didn't realize that problem. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, different languages do this in their own way. Python is a great language too, it's nice to play about with all these different ways of doing things, it's fun!